# Rank of SO(3) and SO(4)?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, rotations

The rank of SO(3) is 1, the rank of SO(4) is 2.
I'm trying to understand the definition of rank of a group with those two examples.

The rank of a group is the cardinality of the smallest generating set.
The definition from Wikipedia is given in the first sentence.
(Link to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_group)

Definition of generating set: "a generating set of a group is a subset such that every element of the group can be expressed as a combination (under the group operation) of finitely many elements of the subset and their inverses. "

In the case of SO(3), the group operation would be (matrix-)multiplication and there is no way one could express all the uncountably many rotations in the xy-plane with a finite product of matrices.

Comment: It is the rank of its *Lie algebra*, i.e., the dimension of a Cartan subalgebra  - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978303/how-to-tell-the-rank-of-a-semisimple-lie-algebra).

Comment: Thank you very much. For my use case (finding the number of Casimir operators) it would be a detour to go over to lie groups anyways.

Comment: Every time anyone defines a function called $f$ which can be applied to both an $X$ and a $Y$, and every $X$ is a $Y$, but the values of $f$ don't agree, Bourbaki kills a kitten. Here, _rank_ is the culprit, but there are many others. On behalf of all of mathematics, I apologize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're asking about the Lie groups $SO(3)$ and $SO(4)$, you're looking at the wrong definition of rank.

You don't want the rank of a group meaning the minimal number of generators; for an uncountable group, that rank is uncountable, as you suspected.

Instead you want the [rank of a Lie group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rank+of+a+Lie+group), and I quote from that link: "For connected compact Lie groups... the rank of the Lie group is the dimension of any one of its maximal tori."

Answer (score 3):

The rank of a Lie-group is the dimension of a maximal torus. In $SO(3)$ a maximal torus is given by the rotations around just one axis, for example $SO(2)\times \{1\} < SO(3)$, and this is diffeomorphic to $S^1$, the circle. Therefore the rank of $SO(3)$ is 1 (the dimension of $S^1$).

In $SO(4)$ you have maximal tori of the form $SO(2)\times SO(2)$, so here the maximal torus really is a torus $S^1 \times S^1$, which is 2-dimensional. So the rank of $SO(4)$ is 2.

Edit: I changed maximal abelian groups to maximal tori. (Thanks for the comment)

Comment: "Torus" is more restrictive than "abelian subgroup": torus is an abelian subgroup consisting of semisimple (diagonalizable) elements. There might be abelian subgroups of bigger dimension than maximal tori, for example $SL(2n)$ whose maximal tori have dimension $2n-1$ has abelian subgroups of dimension $n^2$ (block-triangular matrices $\begin{pmatrix}I_n&A\\0_n&I_n\end{pmatrix}$)