# Computing the rank of the Lie Algebra of the symplectic group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I was unsure if I should post this to the physics forum since mathematician often tend to think differently than physicists, but this is a claim about Lie algebras so I thought this forum might be more appropriate.

The real symplectic group is given by the set of matrices $2N \times 2N$ matrices s.t. ;

$$M^T \Omega M$$

with $\Omega = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1_{N \times N}\\-1_{N \times N} & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now I'm told that the rank of the Lie Algbebra (dimension of Cartan Subalgebra) $\mathfrak{sp}(2N,R)$ is $N$, but I don't understand why. I know that the dimension of the lie algebra is $2N^2 + N$, but how does one compute its rank.

Comment: We have $\dim(L)=rank(L)+|\Phi|$, where $\Phi$ is the root system. The dimension is $N(2N+1)$, as you said already. Since we have $2N^2$ roots, the rank is $N$.

Comment: In general you can tell the rank [as explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978303/how-to-tell-the-rank-of-a-semisimple-lie-algebra?rq=1).

Comment: How did you determine the number of roots?

Comment: The roots are $\pm 2\epsilon_i$ and all $\pm(\epsilon_i\pm \epsilon_j)$ for $1\le i\neq j\le N$.

Comment: And the $n$ elements $H_i= E_{i,i} − E_{n+i,n+i}$ for $1\le i\le N$ form a basis of the Cartan subalgebra. The cardinality is $N$, so that the rank is $N$.